# css Display 3 Columns per Row

Tags: html, css

I'm learning to program in php, am I having trouble displaying 3 columns per line.

The output now:

[image: Output]

```
 <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTOS where EDUCATIVOS=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 img-portfolio">
                    <a href="<?=$row['LINK_DOCUMENTOS'] ?>"">
                        <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="<?=$row['LINK_IMAGEM'] ?>" alt=""> </a>
                        <h3><?=$row['NOME'] ?></h3>
                        <p><?=$row['DESCRICAO'] ?></p>

               </div>

        <?php   
        }
    ?>


   </div>
```

Comment: This is about css not php. Open developer console your browser and play with css codes. Or post css file here and we can figure it what is wrong.

Comment: So what's the behavior of your code now? I mean, in what way the current output is different from the expected one?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap css

Comment: I want something like this [lmage](https://postimg.org/image/czubxzu7d/)

Comment: @OurozZ I've given an answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a little bit of mathematical operation here. Use a counter variable like `$counter` to keep track of how many columns are getting printed in each row, and encapsulate every three columns *divs* with a row *div*. So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTOS where EDUCATIVOS=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $counter = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($counter != 0 && $counter % 3 == 0){
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
    ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 img-portfolio">
            <a href="<?=$row['LINK_DOCUMENTOS'] ?>"">
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="<?=$row['LINK_IMAGEM'] ?>" alt=""> </a>
            <h3><?=$row['NOME'] ?></h3>
            <p><?=$row['DESCRICAO'] ?></p>
       </div>

    <?php   
        ++$counter;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```